# The Probability of an event occuring an exact amount of times

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 40 people in a room and I want to know the probability of exactly 2 people having the same birthday (excluding leap years). The probability of two people having the same birthday is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{365} \right)^2$. So out of the 40 people, if I only want 2 people to have the same birthday, then the probability should be
$\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{365} \right)^2 \binom{40}{2}$.

Could someone check my reasoning?

Comment: Use the same reasoning with the population of the entire earth. Do you think the probability 
$$\left(\frac{1}{365}\right)^2\binom{\approx 7\times 10^9}{2}\ggg 1$$ makes sense?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: No you're right, my reasoning is definitely off. Could you give me a hint as to how to proceed?

Comment: It requires a Permutation and the number of days in a year raised to an exponent.

Comment: Once you've choosen two people to have the same birthday, you're not taking into account that the other 38 people have distinct birthdays (both amongst themselves and from the two people with the same birthday). Also, the probability that two people have the same birthday is $1/365$, not $(1/365)^2$.

Comment: Actually, give two people, the probability for them to have the same birthday (using the standard idealizations about birthday problems) is $1/365$, not $(1/365)^2$. The latter is the probability that both are born on February 10, and doesn't count the possibility that they may share a _different_ date.

Comment: If there are 40 people in the room, then there are anywhere between 1 birth day in the room (everyone has the same birthday) and 40 birth days in the room (everyone has a different birthday). Having only two people sharing the same birthday is the same as saying there are exactly 39 brithdays in the room.

Comment: @DavidMitra: So would it be $(1/365)(364/365)^{38}$?

Comment: Not quite. The probability that the third person's birthday is distinct from the two who share a birthday is $364/365$. But the probability that the fourth person's birthday is distinct from the first three, given that the first two have a common birthday and the third is distinct from this, is $363/365$ (the fourth person's birthday can't be the same as the first two or the third). What is the probability that the fifth person's birthday is distinct from the preceding birthdates, as given, so far? ...

Comment: @DavidMitra: So if I need to make the rest of the 38 people have distinct birthdays, then I should get $(1/365)(364/365) \cdots (327/365)$ right?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to multiply by $40\choose 2$...

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thank you very much for your help! Do you know of any books that have more of these elementary problems?

Comment: I like Sheldon Ross's *A First course in Probability Theory*. (This isn't quite so elementary a problem :))

Answer (score 1):

Since this problem is tagged in homework, I am going to try and give several hints that should lead toward the answer and the correct reasoning.  In this context we can think of the probability of event is (number of ways this event can happen)/(number of possible events).  So look at the following questions:

1. How many different ways can birthdays be assigned to 40 people. You should expect this to be a pretty big number.
2. How many ways can birthdays be assigned and have exactly 2 people share the same birthday?
3. Using this and (number of successes)/(number of events), can you give a reasonable calculation?
4. As a check in reasoning, remember that if we had more than 367 people, then we can no longer have exactly 2 people with the same birthday. At least 2 different pairs of people would share the same birth date (or three or more would share the same) which makes the desired event impossible.  So whatever formula you construct must exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I see that the first question is $365^{40}$. Would the second be $\binom{40}{2}$?

Comment: Think about how you answered question 1, and you will see that $\binom{40}{2}$ is not giving the same information. If exactly 2 people share the same birthday, that means that the remaining 38 people must have different birthdays from each other and from the two who have the same birthday. Think of a simpler case where you have three people, can you answer the question then?